# Is though in the following sentence used correctly as a conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions

Albert Einstein is often considered the most original scientist of the modern age. Even he, though, acknowledged his reliance on the work of others, such Emmy Noether.

I have trouble understanding why is it correct to have "though" in this sentence.

Comment: _Though_ (but not _although_) can be inserted parenthetically like the way it is here. The meaning of _though_ here, like the meaning of _even he_, is related to the superlative in the first sentence. Both refer to a change in expectation. In the case of this sentence, the expectation is that the most original scientists would originate most of their work, but this is not true in the limiting case of Einstein. (And is therefore even less true for less original scientists, by presumption.)

Comment: @JohnLawler — Shouldn't this be posted as an answer?

Comment: Thank you! Should I repost this as an answer?